# File trying to run on start up, how do I stop it?

Tags: boot, scheduled-tasks

Every time I turn my computer on a program tries to run, but the "this software is downloaded from the internet" comes up.

I trust the software, but it is not something that I want to run at start up.  I have looked through my "start up" folder and it is not in there.  I have also looked through task scheduler and I can't find any triggers for it.

How can I trace the action that is starting the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the start menu to search for "msconfig" and hit enter. (type msconfig in Run if you're on XP)

Now, be very careful in this program as you can break a lot of things by misusing it.

Click the Startup tab, and look for your app that you don't want to start on boot. If it's not there, check the Services tab.

Once you find it uncheck it's box, and then click "OK" at the bottom of the window.

Reboot.

When Windows comes back up it will tell you that things were changed. That is normal, just click ok and you're done!

If this doesn't work; look through the app's settings for a startup option. You might actually want to do that first.

Comment: Of course!  I can't believe I didn't check that already.  Thank you.